# Facebook native Android App Access Token

Tags: android, facebook, native

We generated an access token using this link:
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=123456789000000&client_secret=03252f2ff1eddffe234a0dc7256abb8c

And it gave us a, access token like this: AQRtositr-Km47sometextwohp-7heCCDHmKE

But now when we want to authenticate in our native Facebook App its generates the following AccessToken instead:  ABBDSqE43jFSSbrS7ujvyLZClfyKDCZBhAuLXTtr9nwelj4MFwlijzejljEoNItC3lijzm3shemzq3jDFCdAZD

So the question is how can  I generate the native Facebook App access token?

Comment: Why don't you show the code of what you have already tried

Answer (score 0):

Create a Async Request handler in android & communicate with facebook graph API.

[This](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/) link will give you further directions

Answer (score -1):

@Amit @Jan Gerlinger
There isn't such a thing as an App AccessToken. Please see this link:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/